# Segmentation fault (core dumped) in rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu

I've installed Ubuntu 22.04 recently.
Now I have to setup a rails 6 project with ruby 2.6.6.
The setup is complete,Now when I start server and navigate to `localhost:3000`, It shuts down with the below main errors.
I've never caught such errors so I'm a bit confused.
Can anyone here help me?

```
`Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2023-02-04 16:29:10 +0500
/home/ruby-dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@beambox/gems/listen-3.2.1/lib/listen/record/entry.rb:53: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x00007f9602f18140
ruby 2.6.6p146 (2020-03-31 revision 67876) [x86_64-linux]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0013 p:---- s:0062 e:000061 CFUNC  :open
c:0012 p:---- s:0059 e:000058 CFUNC  :join
c:0011 p:0026 s:0054 E:001f28 METHOD /home/ruby-dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@beambox/gems/listen-3.2.1/lib/listen/record/entry.rb:53
Segmentation fault (core dumped)`
```

Comment: Really weird, what’s the exact version of rails ?

Comment: Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72652292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ruby-on-ubuntu-22-04)
May be a problem with rvm and openSSL...

Comment: @SébastienP, Ubuntu 22.04, rvm 2.6.6, rails '~> 6.0.3', '>= 6.0.3.4'.
I am getting the below error when I try to install ruby version less than 3.

Error running '__rvm_make -j8',
please read /home/ruby-dev/.rvm/log/1675680320_ruby-2.7.1/make.log

There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.

Comment: @deikka the issue is openSSL but that question has not resolved my issue.

Comment: Ok so you can only use ruby version between `2.5.x` and `2.7.x` ->  https://www.fastruby.io/blog/ruby/rails/versions/compatibility-table.html

Could you share the content of the /home/ruby-dev/.rvm/log/1675680320_ruby-2.7.1/make.log file please ?

Comment: I've now uninstalled rvm and working with rbenv, it's working fine for me. there was issue with openSSL version which is not compatible with rvm 2.6.x and 2.7.x etc versions.

Answer (score 0):

Consider switching to another version manager like [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv), which can install the necessary OpenSSL library for your current Ruby version.

Another option should be downgrade the OpenSSL. However, note that downgrading the OpenSSL version may cause other compatibility issues.

Comment: Yes I've now started working with rbenv and it's working fine, thanks for your suggestions.